# Testing GCM PeriodicTask

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, periodic-task

I am using [GCM Network Manager (PeriodicTask)](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager#schedule_a_periodic_task) to schedule regular background updates.

This system uses [GcmTaskService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmTaskService) to run the background code. A `Service` extends that class, and the work is accomplished in `public int onRunTask(TaskParams taskParams)`.

The `Service` probably receives its tasks through an `Intent`, so I was hoping that I could run the `Service` myself. However, I have not found any documentation to this end.

The question: How can I test PeriodicTasks without setting the period low, so that it fires sooner (and also much more regularly).

Update #1:

It seems like an `Intent` might be the way to go. Delving into the code... `PendingCallback` is required in order that the `GcmTaskService` can run its Thread.